# Anim: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

Have no idea why i am getting this error can someone help? there is no text being rendered

```
render() {

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
        const animatedHeight = {
                        transform : this.animated.getTranslateTransform()
        }
        return (
            <Animated.View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
                <Animated.View style={[animatedHeight, { position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, zIndex: 10, backgroundColor: 'white', height: height }]}>

                </Animated.View>
            </Animated.View>

        )
    }
```

Comment: please provide a more complete code. this code doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is caused by whitespace hidden inside `Animated.View` children. Self-enclosed the tag should solve the problem.

```
<Animated.View
  style={[
    animatedHeight, 
    {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0, 
      right: 0, 
      zIndex: 10, 
      backgroundColor: 'white', 
      height: height
    }
  ]}
/>
```